# Xcode does not see framework installed via cocoa pods

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to add the `SharkORM` framework to my application but somehow after installing pod which looks like :

```
target 'XXX' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for XXX

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'SharkORM'

  target 'XXXTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'XXXUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

and using command `pod install`; getting this :

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (3.12.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.7)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Using SharkORM (2.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.
```

Which sounds great because the installation is succeed.

In the `AppDelegate.swift` getting error :

Use of undeclared type `'SRKDelegate'` here :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SRKDelegate {
```

I would say that i have to use `import SharkORM` on the top of my file but it does not shows me this file exist. It should - > Inside `Pods` file i have these components then what is going on ? As u can see I am using `Firebase` which is working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you opening your .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcproject

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: Check [this](https://cocoapods.org/#get_started) and take a special look at getting stared. Cocoapods creates a new file which you should open (this instead of the default project file). This new file does include all libraries etc.

Comment: use `XXX.xcworkspace` file to open your xcode project

Comment: @milo526 where in the Xcode project i can find the place for replace ?

Comment: Directory where you save your project you can find. One file you are using `XXX.xcodeproj` and new file created after pod install is `XXX.xcworkspace` use this file

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the framework

   ```
   pod install
   ```
2. Open your workspace XXX.xcodeproj and create a bridging header. To create bridging header

   ```
   //File -> New File -> Header File
   //Save it as a YourApp-Bridging-Header
   ```
3. Compile the SharkORM framework target

[image]

4. Then include the framework header within your app, by adding this to the bridging header

   ```
   #include <SharkORM/SharkORM.h>
   ```
5. import module import SharkORM in AppDelegate class

   ```
   import SharkORM››
   ```
6. Add SRKDelegate in AppDelegate class

   ```
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SRKDelegate
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `import SharkORM` to use the pod. Also, make sure you're working on the .xcworkspace file in the same directory as the project (it's automatically created when you execute `pod install`.